# Ошибка с футером в мобильном Хроме

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, mobile-web

Есть такой код:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    height: 200px
}
```

В десктопе всё работает хорошо, но в мобильных браузерах при скролле вниз начинает пропадать хеадер самого Хрома, а мой футер начинает подниматься вместе с хеадером Хрома:

[image: Проблемки]

(фон - синий, футер - чёрный)

После полного исчезновения хеадера футер встаёт на место. Если убрать "overflow: hidden;" футер начинает вести себя как нужно, но скролл начинает работать с притормаживанием и футер всё равно вибрирует при скролле.

P.S. Почему я использую overflow и скролл вместе: при скролле срабатывает событие перетаскивания элемента сайта.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот фикс решает проблему:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24656868/fixed-position-element-is-flashing-in-chrome-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте убрать правила

```
    left: 0; 
    right: auto;
    top: auto;
```

По идее достаточно того, что:

- он зафиксирован
- его ширина 100%
- он на расстоянии 0px от низа

Comment: Правила действительно лишние (кроме, возможно, left: 0;, так как margin body ненулувой), но удаление их проблему не решает.